# Storybook with Actions Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, storybook, angular-storybook

I am trying to connect the eventemitter of an Angular button to Storybook actions but the action is not triggering. I can see in the console that the button is being clicked. But its not shwing up in the actions tab in storybook.

How do I get the click event to show up in the actions tab in Storybook?

button.component.html

```
<button class="button" (click)="handleClick()">Save</button>
```

button.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ad-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Output()
  buttonclick = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  handleClick() {
    this.buttonclick.emit();
    console.log('clicked');
  }
}
```

button.stories.ts

```
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Button',
  component: ButtonComponent,
  argTypes: { buttonClick: { action: 'buttonClick' } },
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<ButtonComponent> = (args: ButtonComponent) => ({
  props: args,
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the Component decorator

Comment: can you share how ?